# Binding two components properties angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm driving myself crazy trying to understand what's wrong inside my code.
In the template of my 'search-item-main.component" I have two components: 'search-results.component' and 'item-generals.component'.

I've got an input whose text is binded to the input property 'searchText' inside search-result: when i write something inside the input, a function inside search-result calls a searching service and this part works just fine.

Inside search-result.component there is also the 'selectedItem'(with its event emitter) property which is modified by a button declared inside of search-result template.

Then I've got the second component 'item-generals', the ones I've problem with: I've tried to bind the input property 'item' like above to the selectedItem property defined inside search-result, but the ngOnChange event inside it is  not raised.

I've searched all the day online and what's reported below should work, but it doesn't.
I'm using typescript 2.6.2 with angular 5.2.0.

Thanks for the help!

**search-item-main.component.html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:70px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4>search:</h4>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="inputText" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </div>
          </form>
            <search-results [searchText]="inputText" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" ngDefaultControl></search-results>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <item-generals [item]="selectedItem"></item-generals>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**search-results.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Input, Inject, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { LightSearchResultModel } from './../../../models/search-item.models';
import { SearchItemService } from './../../../services/search-item.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
})
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() searchText: string;
  @Output() selectedItemChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public searchResults: Array<LightSearchResultModel>;
  private itemService: SearchItemService;
  public selectedItem: LightSearchResultModel;

  constructor(itemService: SearchItemService) {
    this.itemService = itemService;
  }

  async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): Promise<void> {
    if (this.searchText.length > 3) {
      this.searchResults = await this.itemService.getMatchingItems(this.searchText);
    }
  }

//Called with success by a button in the template
  public selectItem(item: LightSearchResultModel) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(this.selectedItem);
  }
}
```

**item-generals.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { GeneralInfoModel, LightSearchResultModel } from './../../../models/search-item.models';
import { SearchItemService } from '../../../services/search-item.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'item-generals',
  templateUrl: './item-generals.component.html',
})
export class ItemGeneralsComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() item: LightSearchResultModel;
  public generalItemInfo: GeneralInfoModel;
  private itemService: SearchItemService;

  constructor(itemService: SearchItemService) {
    this.itemService = itemService;
  }

//this ngOnChanges is not raise
  async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): Promise<void> {
    if (this.item) {
      this.generalItemInfo = await      this.itemService.getGeneralItemInfo(this.item.itemCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ngOnChanges()` is not invoked, this means that there is no binding change event. Objects are mutable, and most likely the reference to your `LightSearchResultModel` is not changing. Try to clone this object before emitting event. This will change the reference to the object, and the binding change will kick in.

```
public selectItem(item: LightSearchResultModel) {
    this.selectedItem = {...item}; // cloning with the spread operator
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(this.selectedItem);
  }
```

Comment: Nothing happens... I've also tried to do the same thing with a sting instead of  an object so I don't have the problem of the not changin reference, without success

Comment: Is your method selectItem even invoked?  Also, you don't nee the async keyword in front of ngOnChanges.

Comment: Yes, the method selectItem is invoked properly. I've also created another async method which incorporate the body of ngOnChange, so I can remove the modifier async from it, but it doesn't work either. 

I don't understand... Maybe the selectedItem property should have a particular decorator?

Comment: Remove async and await and see if you can print something on the console from ngOnChanges